# remove line where multiple characters are present

Tags: php

I am reading file with file_get_contents.
Some lines can have multiple "=" chars and I want to remove these lines.

I tried

```
str_replace("=", "", $content);
```

but this replaces all occurences of "=" but not removes these lines.

Any idea please?

UPDATE: my content from file looks like this:

```
something

apple is =greee= maybe red
sugar is white

sky is =blue
```

Comment: Could you show us an example of some of your lines in question?

Comment: thank you, I added sample content from file

Comment: have you tried the answer? Does it solve your question?

Comment: thank you, this does exactly what I wanted to do! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing an example of your file/strings, it's a bit tricky to advise, but the basic principle I would work to would be something like this:

```
$FileName = "PathToFile";
$FileData = file_get_contents($FileName);
$FileDataLines = explode("\r\n", $FileData); // explode lines by ("\n", "\r\n", etc)

$FindChar = "="; // the character you want to find

foreach($FileDataLines as $FileDataLine){
    $NoOfChar = substr_count($FileDataLine, $FindChar); // finds the number of occurrences of character in string
    if($NoOfChar <= 1){ // if the character appears less than two times
        $Results[] = $FileDataLine; // add to the results
    }
}
# print the results
print_r($Results);
# build a new file
$NewFileName = "YourNewFile";
$NewFileData = implode("\r\n", $Results);
file_put_contents($NewFileName, $NewFileData);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Try the answer, it should remove the string `apple is =greee= maybe red`

Comment: thank you @justbaron, this does exactly what I wanted to do! :)